# Bash math then pass output to sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'd like to use the index of a for loop in bash to calculate a number then pass that number to sed:

```
for i in {1989..2009..1}
do
let year=i-1
echo $year
find /cygdrive/d/snowmodel/$i/snowmodel.par -type f -exec \
sed -i 's/iyear_init = 1989/iyear_init = '$year'/g' {} +
done
```

So I want to replace the line `iyear_init = 1989` with the line `iyear_init = (the value of i-1, which should be the variable "year")`.

the `echo $year` command returns the correct value, but it seems that when it gets passed to sed it reverts back to treating year like a string.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: put the sed commands in double quotes, sed -I "s/${I}year..."

Comment: Ok found answer after stackoverflow suggested Related questions (I guess my search queries weren't worded very well).

The problem was I needed to replace the single quotes with double quotes because variables inside single quotes don't get replaced in sed. The following worked:

    for i in {1989..2009..1}
    do
    let year=i-1
    echo $year
    find /cygdrive/d/snowmodel_cig/cig_79/bias_runs/$i/snowmodel.par    -type f -exec \
 sed -i "s/iyear_init = i-1/iyear_init = $year/g" {} +
    done

Comment: @mr.cooper you should either delete the question or post the fixed code as an answer (and accept it)

Comment: As far as I can tell, your original code should have worked fine, too.  `$year` is outside the single quotes, so gets substituted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found answer after stackoverflow suggested Related questions (I guess my search queries weren't worded very well).

The problem was I needed to replace the single quotes with double quotes because variables inside single quotes don't get replaced in sed. The following worked:

```
for i in {1989..2009..1}
do
let year=i-1
echo $year
find /cygdrive/d/snowmodel_cig/cig_79/bias_runs/$i/snowmodel.par -type f -exec \
sed -i "s/iyear_init = i-1/iyear_init = $year/g" {} +
done
```